# ttf-mscorefonts-installer is not available

Tags: fonts, software-sources

I'm trying to apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer in Ubuntu 10.04 LTS server, but I get

```
Package ttf-mscorefonts-installer is not available, but is referred to by another package.
```

Do I need to enable a non-standard repository for this to work?

Answer (score 7):

You probably need to add this to your `/etc/apt/sources.list`

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates multiverse
```

Comment: Then run this:
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install msttcorefonts